# Como bloquear download de arquivos pdf

Tags: php

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma EDA para um cliente, o mesmo tem várias apostilas em pdf que quer disponibilizar para os assinantes do curso, porém ele vende as apostilas físicas também, sendo assim ele quer evitar que os alunos baixem os pdfs do site, os deixando apenas para leitura, é possível fazer isso com php ?

Comment: Opa. Não sei lhe informar exatamente o que quer, mas já fiz um serviço que para evitar esse tipo de situação, fizemos assim: quando um usuário vai fazer o download do pdf, pegamos o pdf pai e reescrevemos ele com uma mensagem de alerta de privacidade e junto da mensagem o CPF do usuário em todas as páginas. E além disso colocamos senha no .pdf que é geralmente o CPF do usuário, assim inibindo ele de passar esse .pdf para terceiros ou fazer uma distribuição impressa.

Comment: a maneira que você achou bem interessante, vou procurar saber como fazer e aplicar para ver se da certo assim também, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

http://www.botecodigital.info/php/protegendo-arquivos-de-download-com-login/

Dá uma olhada nesse link, acho que pode ajudar.

*index.php*

```
<?php
  session_start();
?><html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Teste protegendo download autenticado</title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <?php if ( $_SESSION['logado'] == "true" ){ ?>
    <p>Você está logado</p>
    <a href="logout.php">logout</a>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    Você <strong>não</strong> está logado!!!
    <a href="login.php">login</a>
    <?php } ?>


  <a href="download.php?download=putty.exe">Download putty.exe</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

*login.php*

```
<?php
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['logado'] = 'true';

  header('location: index.php');
?>
```

*logout.php*

```
<?php
  session_start();

  unset($_SESSION['logado']);

  header('location: index.php');
?>
```

*download.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

if( $_SESSION['logado'] == 'true' ){

    $download = $_GET['download'];
    if( is_file( '/home/boteco/downloads/'.$download ) ){
        $filename = '/home/boteco/downloads/'.$download;

        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
        header('Content-type: '.$type);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$download.'"');

        readfile($filename);
    }else{
        echo "arquivo nao encontrado";
    }

}else{
    echo "Você não estaa logado. Faça o login para efetuar o download.";
}

?>
```

Na linha 2 chamamos a função session_start() para podermos ler e gravar informação na sessão.

Na linha 4 testamos se o usuário que acessou esta logado na sessão, se o usuário pode fazer o download.

Na linha 6 pegamos o nome do arquivo que recebemos via parâmetro GET da URL, como vimos no arquivo index.php na linha 18 para fazer o download chamamos download.php?download=putty.exe então queremos baixar o arquivo putty.exe.

Na linha 7 verificamos se o arquivo que recebemos por parâmetro existe e é um arquivo, você deve ter notado que utilizamos o caminho absoluto da pasta de download e concatenamos com o nome do arquivo recebido.

Na linha 8 armazenamos o nome absoluto do arquivo em uma variável para facilitar a manipulação.

Na linha 10 criamos um recurso fileinfo, para ser utilizado para ler o mime-type do arquivo.

Linha 11 lemos o MIME-TYPE do arquivo e armazenamos em uma variável, necessitamos pegar o MIME-TYPE do arquivo pois o nosso script de download possui o MIME-TYPE text/x-php e o comportamento do navegador para este MIME-
TYPE é mostrá-lo e não baixá-lo, se deixarmos o MIME em text/x-php e jogarmos o contudo do arquivo para o navegador, veremos o código binário do programa, ou seja, um monte de caracteres estranhos.

Na linha 12 modificamos o MIME do nosso script para o MIME lido do arquivo.

Na linha 13 forçamos o arquivo ser baixado com o nome recebido por parâmetro, lembrando, se não forçarmos ele irá utilizar o nome do script o que não seria algo legal  .

Na linha 15 utilizamos a função redfile que lê um arquivo e exibe ele na tela, como já modificamos o header do arquivo para um outro MIME e para forçar o download o arquivo será lido do sistema de arquivo e enviado para o usuário.

OBS: Só lembrando, a função finfo_open só está disponível no PHP >= 5.3.0, se você utilizar uma versão anterior pode utilizar mime_content_type mas lembre-se de verificar se ela está disponível na sua hospedagem, na minha por exemplo não está e não estou com vontade de me incomodar com eles, fiquei somente com o teste local.

Comment: Respostas apenas com links são ruins. Tenta colocar um pouco do conteudo do link na sua resposta, pois, se o link quebrar, a sua resposta também quebra. Eis o meu -1 até isso ser consertado

Comment: Por que usar snippets em códigos que não são executáveis no `cliente-side`?

Comment: Sua resposta está muito confusa. Começa com um link, então seguem 4 excertos de código e, no final, o corpo da resposta se refere a linhas individualmente, porém sem dizer de qual excerto elas pertencem. Não há uma ideia geral sendo descrita, então fica difícil para alguém um pouco mais leigo (como eu) entender o que está acontecendo